# Clip data to axis in subplots with matplotlip

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to clip data to within the axes bounds when using subplots to create multiple plots.
By setting clip_on = True the data is clipped to the figure but still is shown in the neighboring plot above, but I don't want this to happen. The code below reproducers the issue where the blue line appears in the first plot overtop of the red line.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

fig, ax = mpl.pyplot.subplots(2,1)

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)

y1 = x**2 + 2*x + 2 
y2 = x**2 + 2*x + 3 

ax[0].set_ylim(0, 5)
ax[0].plot(x, y1, color = 'red', clip_on = True)

ax[1].set_ylim(0, 5)
ax[1].plot(x, y2, clip_on = True)
```

[image: Example Picture]

Comment: Please post your plot, because in `matplotlib 3.4.2` I don't think the plot shows what you're describing.

Comment: What version of `matplotlib` are you using, because that is not the plot generated by the current version?

Comment: Added a picture to clarify, also running matplotlib 3.4.2, could there be other settings that are affecting how this is plotted?

Comment: You're sure that if you do `print(mpl.__version__)`, it's 3.4.2? Also, what IDE are you using (e.g. Jupyter, VSCode, Pycharm)?

Comment: Yes, double checked the version number, using Spyder

Comment: With your code, I can't reproduce the plot in Spyder v5.05 or Jupyter Lab

Comment: This is strange, I also tried in a Jupyter notebook and could not reproduce the issue... Is there a bug within Spyder?

Comment: What version of spyder are you using?

Comment: I am running version 5.0.5

Comment: If you're running anaconda try `conda update --all`. Otherwise I'm not sure since you have the same version of packages that I do.

Comment: ran the update and am getting the same thing as before...

Comment: I don't know why. Sorry I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: I had this problem once with spyder v5.05 as well. But my problem got instantly resolved after I restarted my PC. Might want to try it if you haven't done it yet.